# Redirect htaccess php

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect this page with htaccess

```
products_filter.php?f16%5B0%5D=bla+bla+bla&cPath=72&M_ID=12x
```

to

```
products_filter.php?f16%5B0%5D=bla+bla&cPath=72&M_ID=12x
```

i tried this (and many other ways)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^f16%5B0%5D=bla+bla+bla$
RewriteRule ^products_filter\.php$ http://www.example.com/products_filter.php?f16%5B0%5D=bla+bla&cPath=72&M_ID=12x [L,R=301]
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is using `$` (end of input) in this regex:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^f16%5B0%5D=bla+bla+bla$
```

Since your query string is: `16%5B0%5D=bla+bla+bla&cPath=72&M_ID=12x`

Change that line to:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^f16%5B0%5D=bla+bla+bla(&|$)
```

**Update:**

Looking at your question I realize that you are using quite a few special characters that need to be escaped.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(f16%5B0%5D)=bla\+bla\+bla(?:&(.*)|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(products_filter\.php)$ /$1?%1=bla+bla&%2 [L,R=301,NE]
```

**PS: It is important to use NE flag here. Otherwise `%5B` and `%5D` will be further encoded by Apache.**

Comment: Hmm looking at your question I realize that you are using quite a few special characters that need to be escaped. See my edited version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^f16%5B0%5D=bla+bla+bla
RewriteRule ^products_filter\.php$ http://www.example.com/products_filter.php?f16%5B0%5D=bla+bla&cPath=72&M_ID=12x [L,R=301]
```